"Unable to load details about asset" when changing Asset permissions under a cloud asset
I used to share assets with people using the "Legacy" user assets.  I have created a new folder under the cloud assets that I have.  However, when I share it with an earth-engine user, they are unable to access the assets.  The error they get when I share the link created by the code editor is: "Unable to load details about asset" and then the path to my asset.
There never has been any problem when sharing legacy assets.  So I am uncertain about why this is happening.  According to the docs, I am doing everything correct.  Is there something that I'm missing because it is under a project?
